# Log4j2 Howto lookup values from MapMessage in custom fields

Tags: java, log4j2

[Map lookup docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#MapLookup) say that map lookup can be used to retrieve values from MapMessages in LogEvents.

[JSONLayout docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout) say that lookups can be used to retrieve values.

I am trying yo combine these 2 pieces:

```
logger.info(new MapMessage<>(Map.of("key1", "value1")));
```

I use the following config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <JsonLayout>
            <KeyValuePair key="additionalField1" value="constant value"/>
            <KeyValuePair key="additionalField2" value="${map:key1}"/>
        </JsonLayout>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But the value is not interpolated:

```
"additionalField1" : "constant value",
"additionalField2" : "${map:key1}"
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is a bug with log4j2, and raised a ticket in Jira:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/LOG4J2/issues/LOG4J2-2522